# Understanding scala enumerations

Tags: scala, enums

I have to say I don't understand Scala enumeration classes. I can copy-paste the example from documentation, but I have no idea what is going on.

```
object WeekDay extends Enumeration {
  type WeekDay = Value
  val Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun = Value
}
import WeekDay._
```

- What means `type WeekDay = Value` and why do I have to write that?
- Why is `val Mon = Value`?  What does that even mean?
- Why do I have to import the `WeekDay`
  object?  And,
- when I write `val day = WeekDay.Mon`, why is it type `WeekDay.Value`, not type `WeekDay`?

Comment: I've written a small overview about scala Enumeration and alternatives, you may find it useful: pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-enums/

Comment: Sealed traits provide an excellent alternative - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203268/what-is-a-sealed-trait

Answer (score 153, accepted):

the `Enumeration` trait has a type member `Value` representing the individual elements of the enumeration (it's actually an inner class, but the difference doesn't matter here).

Thus `object WeekDay` inherits that type member. The line `type WeekDay = Value` is just a *type alias*. It is useful, because after you import it elsewhere with `import WeekDay._`, you can use that type, e.g.:

```
def isWorkingDay(d: WeekDay) = ! (d == Sat || d == Sun)
```

Instead, a minimal version would just be:

```
object WeekDay extends Enumeration {
  val Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun = Value
}
```

and you do not *have to* import the contents of `object WeekDay`, but then you would need to use type `WeekDay.Value` and to qualify individual members. So the example would become

```
def isWorkingDay(d: WeekDay.Value) = ! (d == WeekDay.Sat || d == WeekDay.Sun)
```

---

The second question is about the meaning of `val Mon, ... = Value`. This is indeed very confusing if you don't look into the implementation of `Enumeration`. This is not the assignment of a type! It is instead calling a protected **method of the same name**, `Value`, which returns a concrete instance of type `Value`.

It so happens that you can write `val a, b, c = foo` in Scala, and for each value `a`, `b`, and `c` the method `foo` will be called again and again. `Enumeration` uses this trick to increment an internal counter so that each value is individual.

If you open the Scala API docs for `Enumeration` and click on `Visibility: All`, you will see that method appearing.

Comment: Thanks, this is very confusing but I think it's right. I will use sealed case classes instead, it seems 100% easier.

Comment: I personally prefer sealed case classes, too. A bit more verbose, but less hokus-pokus with mutable internal counters and so forth. With Scala 2.10, there are some ideas how enumerations (which unlike Java are not a language construct but just a library solution) can be written better using macros.

Comment: @0__ May I ask why and how do you use sealed class to replace enum in Scala? Is there anything wrong with Scala's Enumeration?

Comment: What if Enum values themselves have members? How would you for instance define opening hours for each day of the week like: Mon(8,20), ..., Sun(0,0) ?

Comment: @simou then you should indeed use a sealed trait and actual sub classes. I would hardly call that scenario an "enumeration", though. You might better write `Open(Mon, 8, 20)` and the days would remain a flat enumeration.

Comment: @ZhangXiao they are confusing, that's why I asked this question in the first place :) [sorry for resurrecting old comment]