# Scala, Ord instance haskell like

Tags: scala, haskell, compare

whereas in haskell i can do

```
data ABC = A | B | C

instance Ord ABC where
  A > B = True
  ... (and so on)
```

in Scala i started

```
abstract class ABC
case object A extends ABC
... (and so on)
```

The question then is, what is the best scala solution for this > / < / >= compare problem?

Comment: Wouldn't a boring old [enumeration](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Enumeration) do?

Comment: The thing is that seems very javastyle. There's nothing wrong about it, but i wanted to know if there is a more scalatype way to do it :D

Comment: ScalaZ way: http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Order.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create an algebraic data type like that in scala you should use sealed traits.

```
sealed trait Base
object A extends Base
object B extends Base
```

Then you can write the ordering as wingedsubmariner pointed out above:

```
implicit object baseOrdering extends Ordering[Base]{
    def compare(a:Base, b:Base): Int =  (a,b) match{
        case (A,B) => -1
        case (B,A) => 1
        case (A,A) | (B,B) => 0
    }
}
```

The benefit of this approach is that the compiler will warn you if you don't have exhaustive checking in your pattern matches where you use `Base`.

Now you can do the following:

```
val a:Seq[Base] = Seq(A,B,A)
res2: a: Seq[Base] = List(A, B, A)

a.sorted
res3: Seq[Base] = List(A, A, B)
```

For further information on sealed traits please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203268/what-is-a-sealed-trait).

Comment: That seems the very thing i needed. Thanks! Just a question, does the implicit object definition go inside the sealed trait {} or in a package object?

Comment: If you want an implicit to be in scope always for `Base` you can put it in the companion object of `Base`.  If you're defining a non standard ordering somewhere you should put it at the smallest scope possible to avoid other people accidently getting it.

Comment: May I ask how you would you do that if `Base` was parametrized with another type i.e. `Base[A]`?

Answer (score 2):

Scala has type classes just like Haskell, and uses them in its standard library. `Ordering`, specifically, is the one you are looking for:

```
implicit object Ordering[ABC] {
  def compare(x: ABC, y: ABC) = {
    // Write your definition here.
  }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't write that exactly but found the way around, made abstract class ABC extend Ordering ABC and then inside ABC wrote def compare matching each case object