# scala - Inheritance

Tags: scala, inheritance

Any idea how I can avoid these repeated class parameters?

```
abstract class XClass(  var x:  Int, var y:  Int, var w:  Int, var h:  Int) {...}
abstract class MXClass( var xS: Int, var yS: Int, var wS: Int, var hS: Int) 
                        extends XClass (xS, yS, wS, hS)
class PXClass( var xP: Int = 0, var yP: Int = 0, var wP: Int = 0, var hP: Int = 0) 
                extends MXClass (xP, yP, wP, hP)
def draw(g: Graphics2D) {
g fillRect (x, y, w, h)
}
```

then I have something like this in a `GUI`:

```
  g setColor black
  val cc = new PXClass(200, 300, 10, 10)
  cc.draw(g)
```

So I am giving those parameters as they are needed in the `GUI`!

Thanks

Comment: Could you tell us what you're trying to build here?

Comment: the XClass is a `Piece` class and MXClass is a `MovablePiece` then PXClass is `RectanglePiece` class. Then I need `Piece` class to extend by `StationaryPiece`, thus I am trying to have some movable and statinary pieces in a BoardPanel of different shapes.

Comment: What do all the type and val names stand for?

Comment: they are the coordinates that I may need to build movable and not movable pieces and no mater of shapes !

Comment: they all have x and y coords and w and h?

Comment: yes, because they are geometrical pieces: rectangle or an oval and even if it's an image I should put in a rectangle format or Oval one.

Comment: You may need to know why I need from the beginning the coordinates, but I have in the parent Class, in `Piece` two methods about `collision` and `oleverlaps` and I thing it's necessary for them to be implemented in the parent Class because they are for both valid `movable` and `notMovable` pieces

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to what you said:

> the XClass is a Piece class and MXClass is a MovablePiece then PXClass is RectanglePiece class. Then I need Piece class to extend by StationaryPiece, thus I am trying to have some movable and statinary pieces in a BoardPanel of different shapes. –  Val 18 mins ago

Let's just start out by defining them one by one — let's not use any inheritance because it's not immediately obvious it's even needed; you can come back to inheritance (or some other type of polymorphism) when needed but trust me it's never actually needed:

```
sealed trait                  Shape
case object Rectangle extends Shape
case object Square    extends Shape
case object Circle    extends Shape

case class Dimensions(x: Int, y: Int, w: Int, h: Int)

case class Piece(shape: Shape, dim: Dimensions, isMovable: Boolean = true)

val squarePiece =        Piece(Square,    Dimensions(x = 100, y =. 200, w = 20, h = 20))
val circularPiece =      Piece(Circular,  Dimensions(x = 0,   y = -100, w = 40, h = 40))
val immovableRectPiece = Piece(Rectangle, Dimensions(...), isMovable = false)
```

and then you can define a function to take any piece and draw it:

```
def draw(piece: Piece) = piece.shape match {
  case Rectangle => ...
  case Square =>    ...
  case Circle =>    ...
}
```

...and methods for binary functions:

```
case class Piece(...) {
  def collidesWith(other: Piece) = ...
  def overlapsWith(other: Piece) = ...
}
```

then:

```
draw(immovablePiece)

if (piece1 collidesWith piece2) ...

if (piece1 overlapsWith piece2) ...
```

You're free to make `draw` a method of `Piece` as well, but it doesn't really matter — if you manage to avoid inheritance, all methods become equivalent to plain functions anyway.

There is no need to use inheritance (i.e. subtype polymorphism); it's always best to start out with mathematically purer concepts and avoid `extends` altogether. If you consider the code I've demonstrated, you'll realise that it gives you a way to compose bits and pieces instead of providing monolithic types; it also allows you to convert one type of piece to another by providing an alternative value for an attribute — this is not possible with inheritance; it's not possible to change the type of an object once created.

```
val immovableCirclePiece = circularPiece.copy(isMovable = false)
```

Note that the `Shape` inheritance tree starting with that [`sealed trait`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203268/what-is-a-sealed-trait) is *not* the same as regular inheritance — what it does it defines an [Algebraic Data Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type), which in this case resembles quite closely what would be an `enum` in Java.

---

Furthermore, you could try to extract the data that is relevant to drawing/rendering and put it all in a, say, `Representation` class that holds both the `Point` as well as a rendering function to draw specific shapes. Feel free to ask for clarification — there's a lot to say and I'm only trying to get you started with designing your programs in a more sophisticated manner :)

Comment: it's so interesting your reply, and I have design my program more as in OO Java and still I am mixing the Java and simplifications in Scala. Already I have so much code, and it's functional (but not so nice for the eyes) I will try first to find if I can use with less effort your proposal, then let see if I have further questions.

Comment: Yes, getting away from the Java OO mindset that mainly focusses around inheritance (i.e. subtype polymorphism) is exactly the point of my answer — I'm glad it got thru!

Comment: Heyy, I have combine partly your suggestion and I am so exited, now the whole packages are looking better :D Thnxx

Comment: One thing I missed in your post: you're using `var`s — you shouldn't by default; use `val`s (which is the default with case classes if you don't specify anything).

Comment: I am using `val` whenever is possible but for example in a such case class `case class Dimensions(x: Int, y: Int, w: Int, h: Int)` the parameters are needed to be `var`-s because the position `x and y` of the `shapes` get changed during the time :( Thnxx a lot!

Comment: Still use a `val` -- you can use `foo.copy(x = newvalue)` instead of `foo.x = newvalue`; if your code design doesn't allow for that, redesign your code so that it would; basically this boils down to functional design.

Comment: in my case, because I have a `move()` method that change the coordinates if `pieces` are supposed to move then using `copy` method is making my code hardly readable :(, it sounds like a trade-off in this case, using `var`-s or `copy()` method. And it's not my intention to make the code "pure functional" even working with `val`s I feel more comfortable.

Answer (score -2):

Just write:

```
class PXClass extends MXClass (0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: I just gave more details in my question! I can left without initiating those parameters but it's so boring seeing them repeated from class to class :(, thus I just initiated them with default values.

Comment: Have I understood you correctly: you want to define the constructor parameters only for the parent class and let the child class reuse them?

Comment: I have some general methods (in parent class) that need these parameters in the XClass - parent class and then going further when I construct the childClases I am using those methods but I need to set these parameters with concrete values (like in my case in a GUI class)

Comment: What about using traits then? Instead of defining `class PXClass(...) extends XClass(...)`, you can define `trait PXClass {this: XClass => ...` that contains what `PXClass` was supposed to contain. Then, when you need a `PXClass` instance, simply write `new XClass(...) with PXClass`.

Comment: @AnatoliyKmetyuk let see if I will get your explanation, I will try now if it's functional in my case!

Comment: @AnatoliyKmetyuk: you'll only ever make things more complicated by introducing more and trickier inheritance.

Comment: @ErikAllik, I agree, your solution is more intuitive. Traits would be an overhead here.