# Unable to access to object in a sub-package

Tags: scala

I found an example of how to implement `enum` in Scala and here is what I have:

```
   package org.myproject

   object MyEnum extends Enumeration {
      type MyEnum = Value
      val val1, val2, val3 = Value
    }
```

But nonetheless, I have an error `type MyEnum is not a member of package org.myproject`:

```
package org.myproject.subnamespace

import org.myproject.MyEnum

abstract class MyClass {
  def myEnum123: MyEnum
}
```

Notice that they are located in the slightly different packages.

**UPDATE**: there are 2 errors, actually, it depends on how I define `def`:

```
package org.myproject.subnamespace

import org.myproject.MyEnum

abstract class MyClass {
  def myEnum123: MyEnum // not found: type MyEnum
  def myEnum123: org.myproject.MyEnum // type MyEnum is not a member of package org.myproject
}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this slight change in the import statement:

```
package org.myproject.subnamespace

import org.myproject.MyEnum._

abstract class MyClass {
  def myEnum123: MyEnum
}
```

You can check out the link below to better understand why you have to import the enumeration like that:

[Understanding scala enumerations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067396/understanding-scala-enumerations)

Answer (score 0):

An object declaration does not induce a type declaration, hence the error message. You probably want to declare

```
def myEnum123: MyEnum.MyEnum
```

See http://daily-scala.blogspot.ch/2009/08/enumerations.html for a small tutorial.