# Scala Enumeration giving error

Tags: scala, enums

I am defining a scala enum object

```
object LogType extends Enumeration{
    val value1,value2=Value
}
```

But getting an error :

> object Enumeration is not a member of package scala Note: class
>   Enumeration exists, but it has no companion object.

What might be the reason?

Comment: I'm able to successfully compile a `.scala` file containing just the snippet you posted. Please post code that reproduces the error.

Comment: I tried with scala shell ..its working fine .But in eclipse it is giving error

Comment: In that case it sounds like an IDE issue, not a language issue. Do you get an error when you compile your project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try example from [scaladocs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Enumeration.html). It looks like you have to define type.

```
object Main extends App 
{
   object WeekDay extends Enumeration 
   {
       type WeekDay = Value
       val Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun = Value
   } 

   import WeekDay._
   def isWorkingDay(d: WeekDay) = ! (d == Sat || d == Sun)
   WeekDay.values filter isWorkingDay foreach println
}
```

Comment: The type alias isn't required - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11067507/4070984)