# How to define an enum with specific numeric values in Scala

Tags: scala, enums

How can I define an enum with specific numeric values in Scala and be able to get the value list from the type?

If I define the enum using the `Enumeration` type as follows:

```
object MyEnum extends Enumeration {

  type MyEnum = Value

  val A: Byte = -10

  val B: Byte = 0

  val C: Byte = 10
}
```

and try to get the values as follows:

```
val byteValues = MyEnum.values.toList.map(_.id.toByte)
```

then I get an empty sequence.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to define the enum is:

```
object MyEnum extends Enumeration {

  type MyEnum = Value

  val A = Value(-10)

  val B = Value(0)

  val C = Value(10)
}
```

then getting the values works.

Comment: Note that the `type` declaration is not necessary, it will work without it.

Comment: @Tim, true but then you'd have to use MyEnum.Value everywhere you declare a variable instead of just using MyEnum. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11067507/38368) for more info on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a parameter to the `Value` method to set the enumeration to a specific value. Subsequent calls to `Value` without a parameter will generate the next integer in the sequence

```
object MyEnum extends Enumeration {
  val A = Value(-1)
  val B, C = Value
}
```

#### Update following change to question

It should be obvious how to use my answer to solve the updated question, but here is the code, just in case

```
object MyEnum extends Enumeration {
  val A = Value(-10)
  val B = Value(0)
  val C = Value(10)
}
```

Comment: My question was about specific numeric values, not necessarily sequential. I'll change my question to clarify.